# PHP get_instance / Understanding the Singleton pattern

Tags: php, singleton

I've played around with CodeIgniter, and to expand my PHP knowledge I'm attempting to create my own framework.

The issue I have is I want an equivalent of the CodeIgniter get_instance() function. But through all my searching I just can't understand it, nor do I know whether I'm even using it in the correct context..

I believe what I'm looking for is the singleton pattern, but I just can't work out how to implement it, so can anyone help me out?

I want to be able to access the the $page variable for the framework from within the content function.

[I wish to exclaim this is a simplified version and my coding is normally better than this..]

Before Edit:

```
  <?php

    class Framework {
        // Variables
        public $page;

        function __construct()
        {

            // For simplicity's sake..
            $this->page->title = 'Page title';
            $this->page->content->h1 = 'This is a heading';
            $this->page->content->body = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>';

            $this->output();

        }

        function output()
        {

            function content($id)
            {

                // I want to get an instance of $this
                // To read and edit variables
                echo $this->page->content->$id;
            }

            ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $this->page->title ?></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1><?php content('h1') ?></h1>
        <?php content('body') ?>
    </body>
    </html>
            <?php
        }

    }

    new Framework;
```

After Edit:

```
<?php

class Framework {
    // Variables
    public $page;

    public static function get_instance()
    {
        static $instance;
        $class = __CLASS__;
        if( ! $instance instanceof $class) {
            $instance = new $class;
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    function __construct()
    {

        // For simplicity's sake..
        $this->page->title = 'Page title';
        $this->page->content->h1 = 'This is a heading';
        $this->page->content->body = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>';

        $this->output();

    }

    function output()
    {

        function content($id)
        {
            $FW = Framework::get_instance();
            // I want to get an instance of $this
            // To read and edit variables
            echo $FW->page->content->$id;
        }

        ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $this->page->title ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1><?php content('h1') ?></h1>
    <?php content('body') ?>
</body>
</html>
        <?php
    }

}

new Framework;
```

Answer (score 4):

A *get instance* method usually works like this....

```
public static function getInstance() {
  static $instance;
  $class = __CLASS__;

  if ( ! $instance instanceof $class) {
     $instance = new $class;
  }

  return $instance;
}
```

1. Set up a static variable thats state is preserved with the `static` keyword.
2. Set up a variable that points to the class (makes maintenance a bit easier).
3. Check to see if `$instance` is an instantiated object from this class.
4. If it is not, then we instantiate a new object from this class.
5. Return either the new object we just made or the existing object.

So calling `Class::getInstance()` will return a new object when first called, and [subsequent calls will return the existing object](http://codepad.org/UpCcokxt).

Singletons are often frowned upon for a few reasons, and [Wikipedia covers them rather well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Drawbacks)...

> This pattern makes unit testing far
> more difficult, as it introduces
> global state into an application.
>
> It
> should also be noted that this pattern
> reduces the potential for parallelism
> within a program, because access to
> the singleton in a multi-threaded
> context must be serialised, e.g., by
> locking.
>
> Advocates of dependency
> injection would regard this as an
> anti-pattern, mainly due to its use of
> private and static methods.
>
> Some have
> suggested ways to break down the
> singleton pattern using methods such
> as reflection in languages such as
> Java or PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've edited my initial question to include the singleton where I think it's supposed to go, but I'm getting this error:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare content() (previously declared in /home/beta2/public_html/sample.php:32) in /home/beta2/public_html/sample.php on line 32`

Comment: I'm sort of thinking that I misunderstand how Classes and Objects are supposed to work..

Answer (score 0):

Found a pretty good article on the singleton pattern with PHP.  The guy does a pretty good job on explaining it: http://phpadvocate.com/blog/?p=211